# RenderScript: Can't build examples - 'rs_core.rsh' file not found

Tags: android, renderscript

Use Eclipse Classic with ADT plugin. Tried to make project from existing example of Android-14 (Balls, Fountain, etc.) , but error appears :

> :2:10: fatal: 'rs_core.rsh' file not found

Tried to clean project, fix project properties - no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by re-installing sdk